# Error in vroom:vroom("x.csv") : NA/NaN argument

Tags: r, vroom

I have wrote a tibble using `vroom_write(df, 'x.csv)` in a first script.

Next, when I want to open this tibble, using `x <- vroom:vroom('x.csv')`, it does not work and show me the following error message :
`Error in vroom:vroom("x.csv") : NA/NaN argument`

Could you help me to resume this issue?